# error: 'object' no definition/extension method

Tags: c#, wpf

Using code (shown below) I have got an error that say this:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'RenderTransform' and no extension method 'RenderTransform' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly language
```

I have no idea why this is showing as an error as according to most examples (of this) this should work. Code:

```
public void Rotate(object sender, int rotationAmount, int centerX, int centerY)
    {
         RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform(rotationAmount);
         rotateTransform.CenterX = centerX;
         rotateTransform.CenterY = centerY;
         sender.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *cast* `sender` (which is declared as `object`) to appropriate type:

```
UIElement element = sender as UIElement;

if (element != null)
  element.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `sender` to a type that has `RenderTransform` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sender` has type `object`, which definitely has no `RenderTransform` method.

You should cast it to the type you needed.